# Google Docs Viewer Embedded PDFs don't always get displayed

Tags: html, pdf, embed

I have a webpage where customers can click a link and view a puzzle solution as a PDF or video on YouTube.

The HTML code looks like this:

`<a href="https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&amp;url=PDF URL" target="_blank" class="open-yt-lightbox" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Print Solution</a> | <a href="YOUTUBE EMBED URL" target="_blank" class="open-yt-lightbox" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> Video Solution</a> | <a href="PRODUCT BUY URL" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Buy</a>`

In the code above, **yt-lightbox** is a lightbox whose code looks like this:

```
.shadowed {
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
}



.video-container-wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(37,37,37,.7);
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
top:0; left: 0;
z-index:50;
display: none;
opacity: 0;
}
.video-container-wrapper:before {
content: ' ';
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
}



.sizewrapper {
width: 50%;
/* Would normally be 1920px, limited because codepen's screen is small */
max-width: 920px;
vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
z-index:51;
display:none;
}



#videowrapper {
position: relative;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 aspect ratio */
height: 0;
}
#videowrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}



.close {
position: absolute;
right: -42px; top: 0;
color: #fff;
cursor:pointer;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 32px;
text-align: center;
background-color: orange;
width: 32px; height: 32px;
}



.go-to-yt {
padding: 16px;
margin: 8px 0 0;
float: right;
text-align: right;
background-color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
}
.go-to-yt a {
text-decoration: none;
}
--></style>
<div class="video-container-wrapper lightbox-backdrop"><!--  Lets you restrict the video size to a % of the window (or rather, the backdrop)
      and helps vertically center the block -->
<div class="sizewrapper box"><!--  Close button  -->
<div class="close shadowed">X</div>
<!--  Wraps the iframe and helps vertically center  -->
<div id="videowrapper" class="shadowed"><!--  The iframe with the YouTube video  --> <iframe width="560" height="315" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" id="yt-iframe" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" id="yt-iframe" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

//If iframe exists on page
if ( $('iframe').length >= 1 ) {
  
  // Inject YouTube API script
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // On click of element with class .open-yt-lightbox
      //Firefox needs you to manually hold ( event ), Chrome does not
  $('.open-yt-lightbox').click(function( event ){
    // Prevent link from opening youtube
      // You don't need to link to YT since it's getting the element, not the link
      // But if the user has JS disable, the link will still open the video on YT
    $('#yt-iframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    event.preventDefault();
    // Run the openbox function
    openbox();
  });

  // On click of element with class .close
    // In this case, this is the X button when the lightbox is open
  $('.close').click(function(){
    // Run the closebox function
    closebox();
  });

  // On click of element with class .lightbox-backdrop
    // In this case, the element wrapping the lightbox and iframe elements
  $('.lightbox-backdrop').click(function(){
    // Run the closebox function
    closebox();
  });

}
// Global variable for Youtube API (Yes, this could be outside the document.ready function)
var player;
});

// Youtube API calls this function when it's ready to go
// The name of this function CAN NOT be changed
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
// Set the player variable to a new player (YT API), which is your iframe
  // In this case, the iframe has the ID #yt-iframe to make it easy to grab
  // You can also add your API params here, like events
player = new YT.Player('yt-iframe');
}

// Function to open the lightbox
function openbox(){
// Make the lightbox elements visible
$('.lightbox-backdrop, .box').css('display', 'inline-block');
$('.lightbox-backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'linear');
// Start playing the video
}

// Function to close the lightbox
function closebox() {
// Hide the lightbox elements
$('.lightbox-backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
  $('.lightbox-backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
  //Pause the video
$('#yt-iframe').attr('src', 'about:blank');
});
}
// ]]></script>
<script type="javascript">// <![CDATA[
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "http://www.your_iframe.com/";
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1 && !window.opera) {
iframe.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (iframe.readyState == "complete"){
    alert("Iframe is now loaded.");
  }
};
} else {
iframe.onload = function(){
  alert("Iframe is now loaded.");
};
}
// ]]></script>
```

Sometimes though, the PDF, when clicked, just shows an empty window, with no error or anything.

You have to click another PDF link, that may or may not load.  If it does then you can close out of it, click the original PDF you wanted and it opens.

How can I get it so that the PDF is displayed every time it is clicked?

Would the size of the embedded PDF also be a factor?

Comment: Is anyone able to help with this? I added the code for the lightbox used as well.